# How to show "sent" timestamp in messages app

Tags: sms, settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4

With both my previous HTC One S phone's default OS and the cyanogenmod I put on it a few months later, it was possible to choose the time stamp that shows under received messages in the default messaging app. Specifically, you could choose between displaying the timestamp of the message when it was sent, or when you received it.

I now own a Samsung Galaxy S4, and the messaging app shows the timestamp that you received messages. I really would like to see the timestamp that the message was sent at here instead. But I can't find an option for it.

Is there a way, and if so, how?

Comment: The only way on the Galaxy S4 I know is either: Find a third party SMS app that does this, OR there is an Xposed module for this purpose if you are rooted.

Comment: @RossC that's very unfortunate :( I don't like any of the third party SMS apps and I cannot root the phone as it's not strictly mine.

Comment: You could try EvolveSMS. It's an awesome SMS app... (Not an endorsement or anything, it's just a great app. You can also get the Cyanogenmod SMS app if you want it)